# Continue from the next line after getting exception

Tags: java

I want to continue with the next line from which error generated,

```
try{
    statement A;
    statement B;
    statement C;
}
catch(NullPointerException NPE){.....}
```

Now assume that my statement A throws exception so I want to skip that and continue with B. Don't give my suggestion to put in catch/finally block or any other solution. I just want to know is this possible to **skip and continue with next statement**?

Comment: No , you need to catch exception for each statement separately then. Enclose each statement in try-catch block which I think will look lame.

Comment: You want BASIC's `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT`? No can do in Java. Boilerplate is the only way.

Comment: Yes @MarkoTopolnik I was only wanted that.. but now i need to find alternate solution

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible without the `finally` block.

```
try{
    statement A;
}
catch(NullPointerException NPE){.....}
try{
    statement B;
}
catch(NullPointerException NPE){.....}
try{
    statement C;
}
catch(NullPointerException NPE){.....}
```

On the side note, I don't really think this is nice. If you managed to come to the point where you need this kind of flow control, you need to take a step back and rethink your code design.

Comment: This will not work for me, I have hundred of lines, so i have remain only option is that checking first object is null or not for all.

Comment: I don't know the code but if you have hundreds of lines, which need the same treatment, you really should rethink your designs. At least it sounds as something could be improved there.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to execute statement B if A throws exception. One way is seperately try/catch block and other way is put other lines into finally block.

Answer (score 1):

If your statements are similar and can be paramerized, use a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < statementCount; i++) {
    try {
        /** do what you need */
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

or put it in separate method if it needs more parameters:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < statementCount; i++) {

    }
    execute(params);
}

public void execute(Object... objects) {
    try {
        doSomthing(objects[0], objects[1]);
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

If statements are abolutely different, Java 8 provides interesting solutions: [method references and lambdas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). So you can play arround with somthing like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    execute(someObject, YourClass::method);
}

public void execute(Object param, Function<Object, Void> function) {
    try {
        function.apply(param);
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Like darijan already mentioned you could put every single statement into an own try-catch. Or if you know what may cause the exception you can simply check it befor you execute your statements

```
try{
    if(parameterForStatementA != null) {
        statementA;
    }
    if(parameterForStatementB != null) {
        statementB;
    }
    if(parameterForStatementC != null) {
        statementC;
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    // something unexpected happened
}
```

Verifying parameters is usually more efficient than catching thrown exceptions

Comment: This is not answering what OP asked.